# How do I verify calls being made to a parameter used as delegate (delegation)?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I have a class `A` like the following:

```
class A(b: B) : B by b // Note the implementation of interface B by delegation to parameter b

interface B {
    fun memberFunction() {}
}

fun B.extensionFunction() {}
```

I now want to verify that `B#extensionFunction` is being called. How do I do that?

I can verify `B#memberFunction` like so:

```
class BImpl : B // Dummy implementation needed to instantiate interface B

@Test
fun `memberFunction can be verified`() {
    val bSpy = spyk<B>(BImpl)
    val a = A(bSpy)

    a.memberFunction()

    verify { bSpy.memberFunction() }
}
```

However, the same test for `B#extensionFunction` doesn't do the trick; instead, I get a `java.lang.AssertionError`. The verification fails, because the call didn't happen. (Note that you have to use a static mock (using the `mockkStatic` function) to be able to verify an extension function.)

For reference, libraries used:

- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11
- junit:junit:4.12
- io.mockk:mockk:1.9

Comment: Note that because (in this example) `BImpl` is an `object`, I could also have used `mockkObject` instead of `spyk`. However, using `spyk` works as well and is more general.

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially verify extension function being called on the delegator itself, i.e. in your example `a`:

```
@Test
fun `extensionFunction can be verified`() = mockkStatic("your.package.name.FilenameKt") {
    val a = A(BImpl)

    a.extensionFunction()

    verify { a.extensionFunction() }
}
```

This looks trivial, but if the call to `a.extensionFunction()` is made downstream from another call in your test method, this verifies the extension method is being called on `a`.

This works simply because `a` is a `B` (through parameter `b`). Given that fact, you can verify the call being made on `a`.